# Add Kubernetes annotations on Spinnaker internal component deployments

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

We're using [Kubernetes 1.9](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/providers/kubernetes/) as our cloud provider for Spinnaker v1.6.

In this mode, `halyard` deploys all of the Spinnaker components - `orca`, `rosco`, `igor`, etc. - as Kubernetes deployments in the `spinnaker` namespace.

We want to add custom Kubernetes annotations to these specific Spinnaker pods owing to the way our logging solution for containers is defined.

While we can edit these pods by hand, I was wondering if there was a way to configure Halyard to attach custom annotations on all the pods it creates.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this. We use Kube2iam to give pods specific IAM roles. Without an annotation, pods get the default role which is "deny all". This makes standing up Spinnaker difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While its not documented [here](https://www.spinnaker.io/reference/halyard/custom/#kubernetes), it does look like there is a [podAnnations option](https://github.com/spinnaker/halyard/blob/master/halyard-deploy/src/main/java/com/netflix/spinnaker/halyard/deploy/spinnaker/v1/service/KubernetesSettings.java#L32).

I was able to add the file `~/.hal/default/service-settings/front50.yml` with the following config to get kube2iam annotations on the front50 pods.

```
kubernetes:
  podAnnotations:
    iam.amazonaws.com/role: myawsrole
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the annotation on all services, without having to do it for all 7 ones, individually?